# How to split css and load them only when needed on React+ReactRouter web app (built by WebPack)

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I have a web app built by Web app, which takes a lot of time to first loading.
After investigation- I've tried a lot of improvements, also that one of using only critical CSS on server side rendering.
but now' after SSR has finished- React generates a lot more CSS rules- which are not used at this point,
so my question is:
Is that possible to split CSS and load them on demand (i.e.: on route change)?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `css-modules`.

```
/* style.css */
.className {
  color: green;
}
```

Let's say you have the above styles file. You can use the below code to apply the styles.

```
import styles from "./style.css";
const ExampleComponent = () => (
  <div className={styles.className}>
    Hello World!
  </div>
);
```

You should do the webpack config to make importing CSS files to work.

[css-modules documentation](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically imported components / Async components [react loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using the amazing package: 'react-universal-component',
you can read about it more [here](https://medium.com/faceyspacey/code-cracked-for-code-splitting-ssr-in-reactlandia-react-loadable-webpack-flush-chunks-and-1a6b0112a8b8) and [here](https://medium.com/faceyspacey/announcing-react-universal-component-2-0-babel-plugin-universal-import-5702d59ec1f4).
You can use then the css chunks, or the way I did it-
split css files according to your components, and call them from the component itself, without using a 'wholeCss.css' file or something like this.
This way, you can be sure that no needed css was not loaded.